# Can't access to Object Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building my React Component and got this error when I tried to use a axios request and add that response data to an object. But when I tried to console.log the object, it showed me the value when I expanded the object, but still display null.

```
let id, title, channel;

  let details = {
    timestamp: null,
    views: null,
    likes: null,
    description: null
  };

  if (active == undefined) {
    active = {};
  } else {
    id = active.id;
    title = active.title;
    channel = active.channel;
    let dataObject = API.get(`videos/${id}`, {
      params: {
        api_key: "ab4d78b8-e8ff-4392-bff8-21d1058cd420"
      }
    });
    dataObject.then(result => {
      let data = result.data;
      details.timestamp = data.timestamp;
      details.views = data.views;
      details.likes = data.likes;
      details.description = data.description;
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="videoContent">
      <h1 className="videoContent__title">{title}</h1>
      <div className="videoContent__details">
        <div className="videoContent__details--user">
          <p className="channel">By {channel}</p>
          <p className="timestamp">{dateFormat(details.timestamp)}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="videoContent__details--social">
          <p className="views">
            <img src={viewIcon} alt=""></img>
            {/* {details.views} */}
          </p>
          <p className="likes">
            <img src={likeIcon} alt=""></img>
            {/* {props.details.likes.toLocaleString()} */}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="videoContent__description">
        {/* <p>{details.description}</p> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is what I got from the console:

```
{
  timestamp: null,
  views: null, 
  likes: null, 
  description: null
}
```

```
timestamp: 1537003624000
views: "2,043,765"
likes: "400,058"
description: "Luxury is something everyone deserves from time to time. Such 
an indulgence can make a vacation a truly rejuvenating experience. This video will 
focus a lot on helping the first time or inexperienced traveler head out prepared and 
confident in themselves."
__proto__: Object
```

Edit: My axios call:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://project-2-api.herokuapp.com/",
  responseType: "json"
});
```

Comment: Can you show the axios call with the variables being sent?

Comment: For sure, I've just added it to my post

Comment: It's not clear from the above when and where you're doing console.log(details).  I suspect it's being calling before Axios returns its response.  I'm assuming the Axios call is working because of the details shown, but if you want the UI elements to display the results from Axios, then look up setState on the React site.  Your details object should be state and when axios finishes, use setState to update the state object.  Once you've done that, then use something like this.state.description instead of details.description is in the UI part.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is always synchronous and single-threaded. If you're executing a JavaScript block of code on a page then no other JavaScript on that page will currently be executed.

JavaScript is only asynchronous in the sense that it can make, for example, Ajax calls. The Ajax call will stop executing and other code will be able to execute until the call returns (successfully or otherwise), at which point the callback will run synchronously. No other code will be running at this point. It won't interrupt any other code that's currently running.

to solve your problem you should use promises or Async/await,try to modify your code like below:

```
let dataObject = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        API.get(`videos/${id}`, {
            params:{
                api_key: "ab4d78b8-e8ff-4392-bff8-21d1058cd420"
            }
        }, function(error, response, data){
            if (error) reject(error);

            let content = JSON.parse(data);
            let result = content.value;
            resolve(result);
          })
        }
    );
};

dataObject(url)
.then(result => {
    let data = result.data;
    details.timestamp = data.timestamp;
    details.views = data.views;
    details.likes = data.likes;
    details.description = data.description;
    return (<div>...</div>)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.(error)
});
```